# Prove that $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ is not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x},  & \text{for } x \in  (0, 1] \\ 0,  & \text{for } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

is not Riemann integrable.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not Riemann integrable becasue it is not bounded. Also $\int_t^{1} f(x)dx=-\ln t \to \infty$ as $ t \to 0+$ so  the improper Riemann integral does not exist.